# Save a Rendered table to a hidden field in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

I am building a shopping cart function for my rails 4 app using [acts_as_shopping_cart](http://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart) gem.  The gem helps render a nice table with price, quantities and totals of an order.  I'd like to save this as as an html receipt in my Transactions table under a text column.

These are the views that I want to save:

shopping_carts/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<%= render :partial => 'shopping_cart_item', :collection => @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items %>

<div>
  <div><b>SubTotal:</b><%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.subtotal %></div>
  <div><b>Taxes:</b><%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.taxes %></div>
  <div><b>Total:</b><%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.total %></div>
```

/shopping_carts/_shopping_cart_item.html.erb

```
<div>
  <div><%= shopping_cart_item.item.name %></div>
  <div><%= shopping_cart_item.item.price %></div>
</div>
```

How can I save this as one html block in my Transaction.receipt field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly advice against this. Saving it as a hash/json object might be better?

None the less, you can use render_to_string to save rendered output to a string, which you can then save to your DB.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string

Comment: If I save it as a json object, where can I store it?  (I am new and have not worked with json objects)

Comment: You can save it in the same text field... What is your goal? The reason why I suggest not saving html markup in your DB, what happens if you have to modify the markup? Add a class to the markup? You then have to update all your receipts. If it's a JSON of just the data, then you just modify it in one place, the view.

Comment: I just want a record to the receipt to be able to pull up when looking at transactions from, say...last year.  I've been toying with the idea of converting to pdf and then saving to aws...but I thought there must be a simpler way.  The Transaction just stores the amount/check info/etc...not the itemized purchases.

Comment: I would suggest then storing just that, the amount, check info, and etc in a Transaction table, each with the appropriate column. Then you can pull up Transaction.last, or Transaction.where("amount > 100").count, and etc. Will grant you greater flexibility, especially if you are working with a fixed amount of columns (this assumes you are using a RDBMS).